# Adding matrix col name to a line on a plot

Tags: r, data-visualization

Im using `matplot` to plot a matrix of 20 cols and 400 rows, trying to and a legend for the graph it doesn't work.
I trying to use the `legend()` command But without success.

This is the code for the plot :
`matplot(m, type = "l",pch=1,, main = "matplot function")`
`legend( legend = colnames(m)[1:20], col = 1:20, lty = 1:4)`.
where `m`is the matrix.  Thnx

Comment: When I run a `legend` command like what you show I get an error: `argument "x" is missing, with no default`. Looking at `?legend`, the first two args are `x` and `y`, for where you want to place the legend. See the help page `?legend` for details and options. If you don't want to provide coordinates, the *Details* section says *"The location may also be specified by setting x to a single keyword from the list "bottomright", "bottom", "bottomleft", "left", "topleft", "top", "topright", "right" and "center". This places the legend on the inside of the plot frame at the given location.*"

Comment: Can you be more explicit? What is the x var or vars in m? I presume you want to plot one x var against 20 vars (cols). If so, `matplot(m[, 1], m[, -1], ...)` will do what you want.

Comment: Ive generated a variable that doing a random-walk from a starting value between 0-1 and going 400 steps, each step adding or subtracting 0.03. Long story short it is to generated a vector of 400 random probability values, and the matrix is 20 vectors like this one. The x axis of the plot is step number, and the y axis is probability. The plot each line in the plot shows one random-walk. Hope i explained myself.

Comment: @EyalKatz Did you read `?legend`? The `x` argument in legend does not refer to variables used in creating the plot. It is the desired position of the legend in the plot.